# Activate HDMI Port Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

Im trying to find a way to activate my HDMI port as when i plug my TV in it comes up with "No signal present" on my TV and I cant find it on the Display tab is Settings either. I have looked around but all the problems seem to be related to no sound and not to nothing happening.

What can I do to activate it? I have a Asus EEE PC X101 CH if thats any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebooting, with the TV plugged in. Some TVs are pretty silly with such things, as are some cheaper laptop parts.

Failing that, give these steps a try [from this posting](http://daily.siebler.eu/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-intel-cedarview-atom-n2000-und-d2000-serie/)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sarvatt/cedarview
>   sudo apt-get install add-apt-key
>   sudo add-apt-key 0x4c96de60854c4636
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install cedarview-drm libva-cedarview-vaapi-driver cedarview-graphics-drivers
>   sudo update-grub2
>   sudo reboot

The site also mentions changing your grub config and making sure your not running a PAE kernel. It also suggests disabling AIGLX. I left those steps out because I don't know what they would do. Take a look at the site, see if you think you need to do those steps.

Comment: I tried logging out and in and rebooting but no luck. In the terminal its under "Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller" I also believe its Cedar Trail under the Additional Drivers