# Enable HDMI Port Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have an HP Pavillion dm4 with intel core i5.

I'm trying to get my second screen going but whenever I plug it in, nothing happens. The display settings don't recognize the second output either.

I looked at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234377/activate-hdmi-port-xubuntu-12-04) but it's for Atom chipsets...

Please help.

```
$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
video                  19651  1 i915
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Robson CE [AMD Radeon HD 6300 Series]
$ lspci | grep HDMI
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series]
```

Answer (score 2):

As I looked up your computer, it's about a laptop.

In my case I use following command: `xrandr --output LVDS1 --right-of HDMI1 --auto`

My `xrandr` output:

`$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
1366x768       60.0*+   40.0
1360x768       59.8     60.0
1024x768       60.0
800x600        60.3     56.2
640x480        59.9
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to activate or on it. so that it can have the signal. I mean open your terminal and type as

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of HDMI1 --auto
```

If its worked for you, add it to autostart. so that everytime system on . your Dual screen will be on.

[credit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982974)

Comment: This didn't work here's the output `warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring`

Comment: try with VGA0 ,

Comment: same result. added some more information in the edits above.

Comment: ok look at this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982974